# Перемешать символы в каждой строке

Tags: perl

Есть текстовый файл, в котором каждая строка это цифра, например 123456789, мне нужно каждую строку файла перемешать, что бы получилось к примеру 978654123. Может быть есть какой нибудь простой способ  это сделать, например команда однострочник на perl?

Comment: Базовые понятия: цифра это один знак, так сказать буква, которыми записывается число. Цифр всего десять (в десятичной системе). Число - это количество. Число может быть однозначным, цифра ВСЕГДА состоит из одного знака. В вопросе число. Цифра и число - это как буква и слово. Вряд ли  кто-то путает буквы и слова.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cat test.txt | perl -MList::Util=shuffle -lnE 'say shuffle split("");'`
Если кратко, то мы передаем в пайп содержимое файла `test.txt` и дальше обрабатываем его построчно (-n), с удалением переносов строк (-l).

В коде разбиваем строку на символы и перемешиваем из. Правда, придётся подключить модуль `List::Util`, он идет в поставку Perl.

Comment: а зачем переносы строк удалять?

Comment: По тому, что они попадут в строку и перемешаются с остальными символами. То есть, перенос может быть вставлен в любое место строки. Судя по всему, этого автор поста не ожидает.

Comment: аа, т.е. не удалять, а не учитывать. А то я подумал, что вообще удалить, чтоб потом все в одну строку было :)

Comment: `-l` - это прямой аналог `chomp`. То есть, таки удаление последнего символа из строки. И да, всё было бы в одну строку, если бы не `say`, он восстанавливает перенос в конце строки.